# Share wikitude AR using openvidu

Tags: android, webrtc, wikitude, wikitude-sdk, openvidu

I'm working on a video conference app using openvidu. We are trying to include wikitude AR session in the call.
The problem is that both of them requires access to the camera so I have the next scenario: if I instantiate the local participant video first I can't start the wikitude AR session because video don't load. If I instantiate the wikitude session firstly the other participants of the call don't see the device video.
I was able to create a custom video capturer for openvidu, that imitates the camera. It is required to send every frame  for it to works.

```
package org.webrtc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class CustomVideoCapturer implements VideoCapturer {
    private final static String TAG = "FileVideoCapturer";

    //private final FileVideoCapturer.VideoReader videoReader;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer();
    private CapturerObserver capturerObserver;

    private AtomicReference<Bitmap> image = new AtomicReference<Bitmap>();

    private final TimerTask tickTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tick();
        }
    };

    public CustomVideoCapturer() {

    }

    public void tick() {
        Bitmap frame = image.get();
        if (frame != null && !frame.isRecycled()) {
            NV21Buffer nv21Buffer = new NV21Buffer(getNV21(frame),frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight(), null);
            VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(nv21Buffer, 0, System.nanoTime());
            capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
        }
    }

    byte [] getNV21(Bitmap image) {
        int [] argb = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];

        image.getPixels(argb, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        byte [] yuv = new byte[image.getWidth()*image.getHeight()*3/2];
        encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        image.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

                // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
                Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
                U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

                // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
                //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
                //    pixel AND every other scanline.
                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                }

                index ++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendFrame(Bitmap bitmap) {
        image.set(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper, Context applicationContext,
                           CapturerObserver capturerObserver) {
        this.capturerObserver = capturerObserver;
    }

    @Override
    public void startCapture(int width, int height, int framerate) {
        //timer.schedule(tickTask, 0, 1000 / framerate);
        threadCV().start();
    }

    Thread threadCV() {
        return new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (image.get() != null) {
                        tick();
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void stopCapture() throws InterruptedException {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void changeCaptureFormat(int width, int height, int framerate) {
        // Empty on purpose
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        //videoReader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isScreencast() {
        return false;
    }

    private interface VideoReader {
        VideoFrame getNextFrame();

        void close();
    }

    /**
     * Read video data from file for the .y4m container.
     */

}
```

On the local participant I than use this function to send the frame:

```
    public void sendFrame(Bitmap frame) {
        customVideoCapturer.sendFrame(frame);
    }
```

But I wasn't be able to thake the frames from the wikitude Camera. There is a way to access the frames and resend them?

Comment: I'm using the Native Api sdk, version 9.10.0.  I was trying to include the instance tracking from the sample app in the call video. It is working by I don't know how to share the AR vision with other participants of the calls.I need to access the frames to be able to share them with other participants using openvidu.

Answer (score 0):

Such as of the Native Api sdk, version 9.10.0, according to answer from wikitude support
https://support.wikitude.com/support/discussions/topics/5000096719?page=1 , to access the camera frames a custom plugin should be created:
https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/pluginsapi.html#plugins-api